# Obtener json externo en android con java

Tags: java, android, json

Necesito acceder a un archivo de configuración externo que está en formato `json`.

Tengo este código pero no me funciona:

```
String stringUrl = "url_to_json/configuracion.json";
String respuesta = "";
StringBuilder response = null;
try {
    URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    response = new StringBuilder();
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    respuesta = response.toString();
} catch (Exception  e) {
    respuesta = "Error->" + e.getMessage();
}
Log.d(TAG, "Configuración Menu->" + respuesta);
```

La respuesta que me da por consola es esta:

```
Configuración Menu->Error->null
```

Comment: tu código funciona bien, si pones `stringUrl = "http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json";` verás como obtienes respuesta, por lo tanto o bien tienes un fallo en la url que le das o bien el formato json no es correcto

Comment: @AlbertoMier Primero asegura que la url sea válida, si es así, agrega el bloque que describo en mi respuesta para obtener con más detalle el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu Url definido es incorrecto, no existe o no tiene el protocolo "http://" por esta razón no obtendrías el .json deseado, asegura sea una url válida.

```
String stringUrl = "url_to_json/configuracion.json";
```

puedes agrega este bloque en tu manejo de excepciones para atrapar el error [**MalformedURlException**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/MalformedURLException.html) e [**IOException**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html), para tener más detalle:

```
...
...
     } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            respuesta += "MalformedURLException ->" + e.getMessage();
      }catch(IOException e) {
            respuesta += "IOException ->" + e.getMessage();
      }

    Log.d(TAG, "Configuración Menu->" + respuesta);
```